# Perserving variable scope in callback

Tags: javascript, variables, callback, namespaces, closures

Given the below script, I expected the first time the dialog was opened, `var2` would be undefined immediately after the `open` callback, but the second time it would be set to 123.  Not the case and it is always undefined.  Why?

I then uncommented `var2=111;`  No change???  Does JavaScript not execute linearly? Apparently not completely as it somehow "knew" that `var2` would be defined locally in this callback.  Am I interpreting this correctly?

I then changed `var var2 = 123;` to `var2 = 123;` and all works as desired.

http://jsfiddle.net/q9904tzn/1/

```
var var1=321;
// var2=111;
var dialog = $('#dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    open: function (event, ui) {
        console.log(var1, var2);
        var var2 = 123;
    },
});
$('#open').click(function () {
    dialog.dialog('open');
});

<div id="dialog"></div>
<button id="open">Open</button>
```

Comment: [variable hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your fiddle is almost equal to the one below:

```
var var1=321;
var dialog = $('#dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    open: function (event, ui) {
        var var2; // variable-hoisting
        console.log(var1, var2);
        var2 = 123; //gets initialized only here
    },
});
$('#open').click(function () {
    dialog.dialog('open');
});
```

As you can see, the variable `var2` gets hoisted to the top of the function body and is technically `undefined` in the next line where you log it. You're assigning it a value after you've logged. Try and see what will it log when you assign it before logging. You'd get the correct value.

And since you're declaring the variable inside the `open` function, the variable doesn't persist and is being re-declared giving you the same result every time it gets executed.